# Unable to use curl inside docker container. 172.17.0.1 port 9999: Connection refused

Tags: docker

Whenever I try to use curl in my docker container I'm getting the following error:

```
root@01f9a4b98e94:/# curl -v google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
*   Trying 172.17.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.17.0.1 port 9999 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 9999: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

I've tried using --ipv4 option as well and getting the same result. I'm only having this issue when running my node image and not in any of my other containers:

```
docker run -it --rm node:13 /bin/bash
```

My host IP address is 172.17.0.1 and I'm not sure why its trying to connect to my host on port 9999. Pinging google.com is working just fine:

```
root@b1922f6cac72:/# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.204.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from syd09s25-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.204.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=35.3 ms
```

Comment: This isn't programming or development, but curl supports proxies; does your system and/or any system you are using as a repository have any software installed that would want to intercept web traffic, such as antivirus or 'device management' in an business/organization environment?

Comment: No, nothing like that. Also, I'm able to curl just fine out of the other containers I have on the same system and docker network.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you were right - I've searched my environment for proxy settings and I found that there was a configuration loaded by docker that defined a socks proxy. I guess the other containers worked as they were long running and the proxy file has been created after they were started up so they did not use the proxy configuration.